# How to output XML without the "-05:00" UTC offset?

Tags: .net, xml, utc, offset

We have a VB.Net 2008 console app whose Module1.vb does a few queries from our SQL Server database and outputs them as XML to be sent to our customer.

The problem is that DateTime elements that contain only times (e.g., 1900-01-01 21:26:03.000) are being output to the XML with a UTC (Universal Time) offset of “-06:00” appended, e.g., 13:56:55.0000000-06:00

This gets converted to an hour later when accessed by our customer in the Eastern time zone, so they requested Time values like 13:56:55.0000000, without the -06.00.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Details:

The VS solution has a web reference I’ll call WS.
Module1.vb queries the DB, let’s say the tblStats table, and reads thru the data in a DataReader.  For each row, it does:

```
Dim MyWS As New WS.tblSTATS_TYPE_V1 'which is a complexType in the wsdl
MyWS.Start_Time = CheckTime(MyDataReader("START_TIME"))
```

...where CheckTime is:

```
Private Function CheckTime(ByVal Value As Object) As DateTime
    If (IsNothing(Value) = True) Then Return New DateTime(0)
    If (IsDBNull(Value) = True) Then Return New DateTime(0)
    If (IsDate(Value) = False) Then Return New DateTime(0)
    Return New DateTime(CDate(Value).TimeOfDay.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
End Function
```

… but my addition of the DateTimeKind.Unspecified had no effect.

Any direction anybody can give would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Why not convert the time to UTC and keep it safe? That way nobody has to guess what timezones the data is coming from. If they want to -6, -8 whatever number of hours they can from that.

Comment: *Especially* for a web service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime class. It's offers additional timezone information.